# In an array of pointers in C++ does memory overcommitting result in the pointers to be stored in non-contiguous blocks of memory?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, memory

I was writing some code in XCode and noticed something interesting when I was partially filling an array.  My code was basically something like this (this is just an example for the sake of simplicity):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int** array = new int*[20];
    for(int k = 0; k < 20; k+=3){
        array[k] = &k;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
        bool ptrVal = (array[k] == nullptr);
        cout << k << ": " << ptrVal << endl;
    }
}
```

This snippet of code ended up printing out this:

```
0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
6: 0
7: 1
8: 1
9: 0
10: 1
11: 1
12: 0
13: 1
14: 1
15: 0
16: 1
17: 1
18: 0
19: 1
```

I was expecting this:

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 1
3: 0
4: 1
5: 1
6: 0
7: 1
8: 1
9: 0
10: 1
11: 1
12: 0
13: 1
14: 1
15: 0
16: 1
17: 1
18: 0
19: 1
```

Afterwards I read the article below about how the OS is overcommitting memory:
[C++ memory allocation for an array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323666/c-memory-allocation-for-an-array-of-pointers#)

Does the OS deliberately allocate non-contiguous blocks of memory for an array of pointers that has been partially filled?  If so why does it do this and what could be the reasons for the results shown in my sample code?

Comment: `array[k]` in the second loop causes undefined behaviour - the pointer pointed to a variable that no longer exists. The two `k` are different variables (with non-overlapping scopes)

Comment: Also you cause undefined behaviour by using uninitialized pointers (the loop skips in steps of 3)

Comment: @Eichhörnchen evaluating dangling pointers is undefined behaviour already (before we get so far as comparing)

Comment: @M.M So if you have uninitialized/dangling pointers how come when the elements of the array are printed out 0s and 1s appear in random order?

Comment: [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) means anything can happen

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
int** array = new int*[20];
for(int k = 0; k < 20; k+=3){
    array[k] = &k;
}
```

after that, `k[1], k[2], [k4], k[5] ..` are left uninitialized. They are not set to `nullptr` by the line that allocates the pointers.

As a consequence the line,

```
    bool ptrVal = (array[k] == nullptr);
```

is cause for undefined behavior.

You can make the pointers equal to `nullptr` at allocation time by using:

```
int** array = new int*[20]{};
```

Comment: @R Sahu your suggestion results in a compile time error.  This is the compiler I'm using if you're curious: Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix

Comment: @Jamaal that compiler defaults to 2003 mode  , use `-std=c++14` flag, or change `{}` to `()`

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming uninitialized elements of array are set to 0. They are not.
If you add

```
    memset(array, 0, sizeof(*array)*20);
```

Before the first loop, then your output will be what you were expecting.

Comment: I understand that memset would result in the desired output.  But I'm wondering if an array does not have all its elements initialized, why do the elements appear to have 0s and 1s appear in random order when printed out?

Comment: In general, uninitialized heap contains random data. Therefore, when you use uninitialized heap, output from uninitialized portions of it is random. The heap implementation depends on the operating system and compiler. However, if you want deterministic behavior, of your code, the heap has to be initialized after allocation. Period.